# How to get Visual Studio to break on Selenium Exceptions?

Tags: visualstudio, selenium-webdriver-c#

Below are the categories of exceptions that I can choose to break on in Visual Studio (2019).  Where should I go to find the Selenium/WebDriver Exceptions?  I want to tell VS to break on all OpenQA.Selenium Exceptions, even when those exceptions are caught.  To do that, I need to select those exceptions on this list.  But searching for OpenQA.Selenium (or "Selenium", or "Webdriver") in this list produces no hits.  Do I need to do something in Visual Studio to import those exception definitions?

[image: List of Exception Settings in Visual Studio. Includes: C++, Common Language Runtime, GPU Memory Access, Java, JavaScript, Managed Debugging Assistants, Node.js, Webkit JavaScript, Win32]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS lists the exceptions from the CLR or the languages that are [supported by IDE](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/web/languages/).

Selenium is a ***3rd party*** library and therefore is not present there. In short - you can't manually add it to the IDE settings.

As a workaround - you can configure **[Just My Code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2019)** feature, which will allow you to debug the non-user (Selenium) code, if you need to.

Comment: Gotcha.  Many thanks for clarifying.